# Create list from another list by matching values of keys

Tags: python

Hello I wanted to create a list using loop. There some value should come from second list by matching their values with corresponding keys as following

```
listA = [
  {
    "name": "name sample 1",
    "original_name" : "original name sample 1",
  },
  {
    "name": "name sample 2",
    "original_name" : "original name sample 2",
  }
  ...
]

listB = [
  {
    "address": "address sample 1",
    "original_address" : "original address sample 1",
  },
  {
    "address": "address sample 2",
    "original_address" : "original address sample 2",
  }
  ...
]
```

I have another list like this bellow

```
dataList = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "created_at": "date 1",
    "name": "name sample 1",
    "address": "address sample 1",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "created_at": "date 2",
    "name": "name sample 2",
    "address": "address sample 2",
  }
  ...
]
```

I have tried like below code

```
finalList = []
dataJson = {}
for data in dataList:
   for lista in listA:
      if "name" in data and (data["name"] == lista["name"]):
         dataJson = {
             "id": data["id"],
             "created_at": data["created_at"],
             "name": data["id"],
             "original_name" : lista["original_name"], 
             "address": data["id"],
          }
         finalList.append(dataJson)
```

this working but i can not do for original_address.

I wanted to create final list which will included with "original_name" from listA and "original_address" from listB based on matching "name" and "address" with dataList and listA, listB so the final list should be like below

```
finalList = [
  {
    "id": "1"
    "created_at": "date 1"
    "name": "name sample 1",
    "original_name" : "original name sample 1",
    "address": "address sample 1",
    "original_address" : "original address sample 1",
  },
  {
    "id": "2"
    "created_at": "date 2"
    "name": "name sample 2",
    "original_name" : "original name sample 2",
    "address": "address sample 2",
    "original_address" : "original address sample 2",
  }
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want to keep the original dataList I guess this is one way to do it also:

```
from copy import deepcopy

listA = [
  {
    "name": "name sample 1",
    "original_name" : "original name sample 1",
  },
  {
    "name": "name sample 2",
    "original_name" : "original name sample 2",
  }
]

listB = [
  {
    "address": "address sample 1",
    "original_address" : "original address sample 1",
  },
  {
    "address": "address sample 2",
    "original_address" : "original address sample 2",
  }
]

dataList = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "created_at": "date 1",
    "name": "name sample 1",
    "address": "address sample 1",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "created_at": "date 2",
    "name": "name sample 2",
    "address": "address sample 2",
  }
]

finalList = deepcopy(dataList)
for entry in listA+listB:
    if "name" in entry:
        for data in finalList:
            if data['name'] == entry['name']:
                data['original_name'] = entry['original_name']
    elif "address" in entry:
        for data in finalList:
            if data['address'] == entry['address']:
                data['original_address'] = entry['original_address']

print(dataList)
print(finalList)
```

Results:

```
[
    {
        'id': '1',
        'created_at': 'date 1',
        'name': 'name sample 1',
        'address': 'address sample 1'
    },
    {
        'id': '2',
        'created_at': 'date 2',
        'name': 'name sample 2',
        'address': 'address sample 2'
    }
]

[
    {
        'id': '1',
        'created_at': 'date 1',
        'name': 'name sample 1',
        'address': 'address sample 1',
        'original_name': 'original name sample 1',
        'original_address': 'original address sample 1'
    },
    {
        'id': '2',
        'created_at': 'date 2',
        'name': 'name sample 2',
        'address': 'address sample 2',
        'original_name': 'original name sample 2',
        'original_address': 'original address sample 2'
    }
]
```

Comment: this working fine as I tested. thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient and scalable approach would be create a dict that maps values of the main keys (such as `'name'` and `'address'`) to the rest of the records (which contains `'original name'` and `'original address'`) in the input lists, so that `dataList` can be iteratively updated by merging with the corresponding records by the main keys. This way, nothing but the main keys need to be hard-coded, and the number of main keys and source lists can easily increase:

```
for key, source in ('name', listA), ('address', listB):
    original = {record.pop(key): record for record in source}
    for record in dataList:
        record |= original[record[key]]
```

`dataList` becomes:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "created_at": "date 1",
        "name": "name sample 1",
        "address": "address sample 1",
        "original_name": "original name sample 1",
        "original_address": "original address sample 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "created_at": "date 2",
        "name": "name sample 2",
        "address": "address sample 2",
        "original_name": "original name sample 2",
        "original_address": "original address sample 2"
    }
]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/OJioIU

Comment: I do like your approach, although it might add additional info that the user doesn't want

Answer (score -1):

Hope this help you:

```
finalList = list()

for data in dataList:
    original_name = next((a.get("original_name") for a in listA if a["name"] == data["name"]), None)
    original_address = next((b.get("original_address") for b in listB if b["address"] == data["address"]), None)
    finalList.append({**data, **{"original_name": original_name, "original_address": original_address}})
```

Now, finalList is

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "created_at": "date 1",
    "name": "name sample 1",
    "address": "address sample 1",
    "original_name": "original name sample 1",
    "original_address": "original address sample 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "created_at": "date 2",
    "name": "name sample 2",
    "address": "address sample 2",
    "original_name": "original name sample 2",
    "original_address": "original address sample 2"
  }
]
```

Comment: I am getting "errorType": "StopIteration", error

Comment: StopIteration caused a value return None. To fix it, use `next(generator_expression, None)` . It will return None when original_name or original_address  dont any match. I will update the answer for this case

Comment: Updated, try again